# iOS: Pull To Refresh error

Tags: ios, uitableview, frameworks, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm trying to implement a "pull to refresh" functionality to my table views.

I found a couple of classes that should do the trick ([iStopped's PullToRefreshView](https://github.com/iStopped/PullToRefreshView) & [Leah's PullToRefresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh))

Both classes throws me an error about undefined symbols for i386...

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PullToRefreshView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FeaturedTableView.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thing is.. I linked against QuartzCore.framework in the Build Phases..
And in the Build Settings, under "architectures" (and "valid architectures"), I see both "armv6" & "armv7".

I searched around the web for that error regarding PullToRefresh, and all I could find is that the framework is missing... but it isn't (I even removed it and re-added it).

I also came across [this tutorial](http://sonnyparlin.com/2011/12/pulltorefresh-ios-5-and-arc-tutorial/), which says I need to Refactor (edit -> refactor) my project (convert to Objective-C ARC), but I can't do that because when I choose my target, I get LOTS of errors (especially from the Facebook SDK).

Isn't there a simple way to add a pull to refresh functionality? :)

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: How are you adding PullToRefresh(View)? Are you doing it with "File>Add Files To" or by compiling a framework and linking it?

Comment: Thanks, I'm just dragging the files to the project with the "copy files" option... following the ReadMe file. Does it make a difference if I do it through the File menu?

Comment: issue has been resolved. I posted the answer at the bottom here. Thanks, jrtc27, for making me check again the import process.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the actual issue:

I have several Targets that share the most of the project's code.
When I was importing the PullToRefresh class, I *de-selected* all of the Targets, because I noticed that all the other shared files in the project had all the targets in their properties de-selected...

When I re-imported the class and *selected* all the Targets, everything works fine... I'm now actually using the [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) and it's working great.

So I guess de-selecting all targets doesn't mean that it's completely shared across all targets :) I wonder why all my view controllers and all don't have any targets checked and they are available to all targets...

But the issue has been resolved (^_^)

Thank you, @jrtc27 , for making me check the import procedure again.

Answer (score 0):

(Without seeing your code) You need to import the **`PullToRefreshView`** class.

```
#import "PullToRefreshView.h"
```

Or you need to make sure that your table controller (which seems to be **`FeaturedTableView`**) is a `PullRefreshTableViewController`.

### Example

```
@interface FeaturedTableView : PullRefreshTableViewController
{
    /* your objects here */
}
@end
```